# How to disable child inputs?

Tags: angular

I have parent component :
html:

```
<select class="form-control" type="text" required [disabled]="populateData">
      <option value=""></option>
       <option *ngFor ="let contact of contacts" [value]="contact.id">{{contact.id}} - {{contact.customerName}}, {{contact.ptechnologyName}}, {{contact.mainlocationName}}  </option>
 </select>
```

ts:

```
   populateData: Boolean = true;
```

Inside that component i have child component:

ts:

```
 <app-user-detail></app-user-detail>
```

html:

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label>Broj</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control-full" placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="prepaidDetails.mobile" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [disabled]="populateData">
      </div>
 </div>
```

Now i want when i change on parent component populateData to true to get that in child component. Any suggestion?

Comment: where is app-user-detail used in html?

Comment: Parent has `populateData`, thus you can add an input for your child `<app-user-detail [populateData]="populateData">` and define it like `@Input() public populateData: boolean;`. This is it?

Comment: yes...this is it...u can post r answer i will accept it